# Creating class variables in Python with inheritance

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        type(self).label_type = xyzzy(self.__class__.__name__)

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Y, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I create a new instance of Y, a class variable called `label_type` is created using `Y`, not `X`. This is good and works fine.

But it burns me that I have to wait until there's an instance of Y before the class variable is created. How can I set `label_type` when class Y is compiled, not when it is instantiated?

EDIT - I have numerous subclasses that are derived from X. I want to push as much of the work into X as possible.

Comment: Have either of the answers addressed your issue? If not, could you clarify further?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a metaclass to do this kind of thing. Here's a trivial example to demonstrate:

```
class NameLabelMeta(type):

    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        """Create a new class and label it with its name."""
        cls = super(NameLabelMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        cls.label_type = name  # or xyzzy(name), or whatever
        return cls
```

In use:

```
>>> class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = NameLabelMeta  # 2.x syntax


>>> class Y(X):
    pass

>>> Y.label_type
'Y'
```

Note that `Y` transparently inherits the metaclass from `X`, so doesn't need to implement anything at all for the correct behaviour to occur. It's also much more efficient, as it doesn't happen again every time you create a new instance of the class.

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I need time to understand it.

Comment: @TonyEnnis that's fair enough! A metaclass lets you customise creation of classes, in the same way that a class lets you customise creation of instances. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/3001761

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to set the `label_type` dynamically? Why not use a "static variable" such as

```
class X(object):
    LABEL_TYPE = 'X'

class Y(X):
    pass

print Y().LABEL_TYPE # Prints 'X'
```

Comment: I believe the OP would like `Y.LABEL_TYPE` to be derived from `'Y'`, not `'X'`.

Comment: Additional reason added to OP